In cnosdb query, when there are tags in the filter tag, should the duplicate be removed
I have a lot of items displayed when I select * and tag filter normally, but I find that when I filter with count(*) and tag, the number of items displayed becomes 1. Is it because tag automatically deduplicates items? It's hard to figure out

